# Convert dataframe column values to new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing some data, which I want to transform, so that the values of one column define the new columns.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([['a','a','b','b'],[6,7,8,9]]).T
>>> df
   A  B
0  a  6
1  a  7
2  b  8
3  b  9
```

The values of the column `A` shall be the column names of the new dataframe. The result of the transformation should look like this:

```
   a  b
0  6  8
1  7  9
```

What I came up with so far didn't work completely:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({ k : df.loc[df['A'] == k, 'B'] for k in df['A'].unique() })
     a    b
0    6  NaN
1    7  NaN
2  NaN    8
3  NaN    9
```

Besides this being incorrect, I guess there probably is a more efficient way anyway. I'm just really having a hard time understanding how to handle things with pandas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were almost there but you need the `.values` as the list of array and then provide the column names.

```
pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame({ k : df.loc[df['A'] == k, 'B'].values for k in df['A'].unique() }), columns=df['A'].unique())
```

Output:

```
    a   b
0   6   8
1   7   9
```

Comment: I tried this with my real data, and it didn't work. If you change the input data to have two further entries for each key, i.e. `df = pd.DataFrame([['a','a','a','b','b','b'],[4,5,6,7,8,9]]).T`, then it throws an 'AssertionError'.

Comment: Your first solution `pd.DataFrame({ k : df.loc[df['A'] == k, 'B'].values for k in df['A'].unique() })` works like a charm.

Comment: @KorbenDose, you are right. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Using a dictionary comprehension with `groupby`:

```
res = pd.DataFrame({col: vals.loc[:, 1].values for col, vals in df.groupby(0)})

print(res)

   a  b
0  6  8
1  7  9
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `set_index`, `groupby`, `cumcount`, and `unstack`:

```
(df.set_index(['A', df.groupby('A').cumcount()])['B']
   .unstack(0)
   .rename_axis([None], axis=1))
```

Output:

```
   a  b
0  6  8
1  7  9
```